# Isabelle order type-class on lambda expressions

Tags: isabelle

I found this expression somewhere in Isabelle's standard library and tried to see what `value` does with it

```
value "(λ x::bool . ¬x) ≤ (λ x . x)"
```

It outputs `False`. What is the meaning of `≤` here? Ideally, where can I find the exact `instantiation` of it? When I Ctrl+Click on the lambda symbol, jEdit doesn't take me anywhere. Is `λ` part of meta logic then? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This and many other things are defined in `Lattices.thy` theory in `Main` library

https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL/Lattices.html

under the following section.

```
subsection ‹Lattice on \<^typ>‹_ ⇒ _››

instantiation "fun" :: (type, semilattice_sup) semilattice_sup
begin

definition "f ⊔ g = (λx. f x ⊔ g x)"

lemma sup_apply [simp, code]: "(f ⊔ g) x = f x ⊔ g x"
  by (simp add: sup_fun_def)

instance
  by standard (simp_all add: le_fun_def)

end
```